# How to auto scale size of distant objects in ThreeJS?

Tags: camera, three.js, distance, percentage, difference

I'm using perspective camera and want to make distant object visual size like close objects.

I check distance from close and distant objects

```
function getDistance(mesh1, mesh2) {
    var dx = mesh1.position.x - mesh2.position.x;
    var dy = mesh1.position.y - mesh2.position.y;
    var dz = mesh1.position.z - mesh2.position.z;
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz);
}
```

and check every loop:

```
var diff = (getDistance(camera, mesh5) - getDistance(camera, mesh1)) / (getDistance(camera, mesh5) + getDistance(camera, mesh1)) * 100;
console.log(diff);
mesh5.scale.set(diff, diff, 1);
```

But size is not equivalent.

Comment: Why not to use `THREE.OrthographicCamera()` for this purpose?

Comment: Because I need to use perspective view for main 3d model, only for sprites need change size

Comment: Read [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40452050/4045502)